# What do you do when a family member won't pay you back?

Tags: family, loans, debt, repayment

What do you do when a family member won't pay you back?

Comment: An excellent personal finance question?

Comment: "Before you loan a friend money, ask yourself which you need more."

Answer (score 18):

- If you care about the relationship, forgive the debt.
- If you don't care about the relationship, **AND** you have the loan agreement in writing take them to court.
- If you don't care about the relationship, and don't have anything in writing, write off the money.

Trying to forcefully reclaim the money *will* ruin the relationship.  In general it's bad practice to *loan* money to family.

Answer (score 5):

Never loan money to family or friends with the intention of getting it back.  If you take him/her to court, and the claim is valid, sure you get your money back, you lose a friend/family member.

Answer (score 2):

Take them to small claims court or just forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

Pretend it was a gift all along, be happy that you could help out your family when they needed it and remember your lesson for the future.

Answer (score 0):

What do you do?

1. Remember never to do it again.
2. Tell your other relatives, so they won't get stiffer either.